# Suggestion for labeling my plots

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have several figures like the one in the below:

```
logdata001 = {{2., 0.961973}, {3., Around[1.0615567283096428`, 0.0829973108613199]}, {4., Around[1.6148368066515686`, 0.19646949168300437`]}, {4.9542, Around[1.9799984788912215`, 0.22744045238090516`]}, {5.97728, Around[3.0256586135432313`, 0.4441779651996193]}, {6.96578, Around[4.751870201707909, 0.5186565213910944]}, {7.96578, Around[8.353662042037488, 1.0279834833435684`]}, {8.96578, Around[13.333103260464355`, 1.3421587275991116`]}}

logdata002 = {{2., 1.36736}, {3., 1.50511}, {4., 1.67348}, {4.9542, 2.25512}, {5.97728, 3.0625}, {6.96578, 4.38542}, {7.96578, 7.34536}, {8.96578, 12.6508}}


ListLinePlot[{logdata002, logdata001}, IntervalMarkers -> "Fences", Frame -> True, 
PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Disk[], {Thick, Circle[]}}], 0.04}, LabelStyle -> {22, GrayLevel[0]}, 
PlotStyle -> {{RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], Thick}, {RGBColor[0.922526, 0.385626, 0.209179], Thick}}, ImageSize -> Large, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"},
PlotLegends -> Placed[PointLegend[{Style["Theory", 
FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"], 
Style["Experiment", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"]}, 
LegendFunction -> "Frame"], Scaled[{0.2, 0.77}]], 
FrameLabel -> {Style["City", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"], 
Style["Crimes", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"]}, FrameTicks -> {{{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14}, 
None}, {{{2, 4}, {3, 8}, {4, 16}, {5, 31}, {6, 63}, {7, 125}, {8, 
  250}, {9, 500}}, None}}]
```

[image]

I want to label these figures as (A), (B), and ... . What is the best way to do this and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am leaving this on top because I like it the most

**Edit 2:**

```
text0 = "Some poor souls trying to keep the referees happy";
text1 = "Figure (A)";
text2 = "Figure (B)";
text3 = "Figure (C)";
Grid[{{Style[text0, FontSize -> Scaled[0.02], 
    FontFamily -> "League Gothic"], 
   SpanFromLeft}, {Style[text1, FontSize -> Scaled[0.02], 
    FontFamily -> "Alegreya SC"], 
   Style[text2, FontSize -> Scaled[0.04], 
    FontFamily -> "Herculanum"]}, {plot, 
   plot}, {Style[text3, FontSize -> Scaled[0.05], 
    FontFamily -> "Felipa"], SpanFromLeft}, {plot, SpanFromLeft}}, 
 ItemSize -> Scaled[0.5]]
```

> [image: final]

**Edit 3:** in the comments it was requested to place `Figure A` in the bottom and to the left, while keeping the rest aligned. The following

```
Labeled[ListLinePlot[{logdata002, logdata001},
  IntervalMarkers -> "Fences",
  Frame -> True,
  PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Disk[], {Thick, Circle[]}}], 0.04}, 
  LabelStyle -> {22, GrayLevel[0]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 
     Thick}, {RGBColor[0.922526, 0.385626, 0.209179], Thick}},
  ImageSize -> Large,
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[PointLegend[{Style["Theory", 
       FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"], 
      Style["Experiment", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"]}, 
     LegendFunction -> "Frame"], Scaled[{0.2, 0.77}]], 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["City", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"],
     Style["Crimes", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"]}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14}, 
     None}, {{{2, 4}, {3, 8}, {4, 16}, {5, 31}, {6, 63}, {7, 125}, {8,
        250}, {9, 500}}, None}}], 
 Grid[{{Style["Figure A", FontSize -> Scaled[0.02], 
     FontFamily -> "League Gothic"]}}], {{Left, Bottom}}]
```

> [image: pl]

**Orignal**

```
text = "some words";
Grid[{{plot}, {Style[text, FontSize -> Scaled[0.05], 
    FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}}, ItemSize -> Scaled[0.5]]
```

[image: plot]

where in the above `plot=ListLinePlot[....]`

**Edit 1:** another possible way is

```
Column[{plot, 
  Style[text, FontSize -> Scaled[0.05], FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}, 
 ItemSize -> Scaled[0.5]]
```

Comment: hey @Marteen can you please edit your question and let us know where the header should go? I had a look at the second link you provided and quite frankly I would place the header below each plot, but it's a matter of taste

Comment: @Marteen yup, but you can place it on top if you add a minor adjustment to what I suggested; check this `Grid[{{Style[text, FontSize -> Scaled[0.02], 
    FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}, {plot}}, ItemSize -> Scaled[0.5]]`

Comment: @Marteen the important -in my opinion- is to check how these numbers are placed `Grid[{{"1", "2", "3"}, {"4", "5", "6"}, {"7", "8", "9"}}]` and then you can modify appropriately and re-size your plots with headers etc

Comment: @Marteen try in your plot to do `FrameLabel -> {Row[{Style["Figure A", 
     FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"], Spacer[20], 
    Style["City", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"]}], 
  Style["Crimes", FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"]}` and tell me if that's what you want

Comment: @Marteen have a look at the second edit. With all the commands I have included for you, if you look up the docs you should be able to align all the plots and all the headers. I have used different fonts and sizes to show you that you can change them independently. I, also, included a general title to show you how it's done and how to align it.

Comment: @Marteen and perhaps have a look at edit 3

Comment: @Marteen not sure how to do that with the code above. It would need a total re-writing. I would still go with edit 2 for presenting in any journal I have published. It's the cleanest. and even with the four plots from your other question it presents itself nicely. And in the other question, try adding at the end of each plot `ImageSize -> 100` and then `Grid` them together

Comment: @Marteen I showed you how to do it and I am leaving a comment in the hopes that it will improve future posts :-)